# WPF C# Как сделать событие selection changed прямым

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

У меня на TabControl стоит событие SelectionChanged, внутри TabControl стоят два DataGrid, когда источником события является DataGrid, то на TabControl тоже оно срабатывает. Можно ли сделать, чтобы событие срабатывало только на одном элементе?

Comment: Пока что сделал такую проверку в SelectionChanged TabControl-а:
if(e.OriginalSource is TabControl)

Comment: У события есть поле Handled или типа того, его выставьте в true

Comment: Это если обрабатывать вложенные события, или в событии DataGrid-е?

Comment: ну вы попробуйте и так и так